# Image Size via CSS

Tags: css, image, responsive-design

I have this lines below for a reponsive site,
I need to put "no-image" class when there is no image,

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <img id="first" width=275 height=385 src="flower-275x385.jpg" />
        <img id="second" width=275 height=385 class="no-image" src="blank-1x1.png" />
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .row {
        width:400px ;
    }
    .column {
        width:50% ;
    }

    .column img {
        width:100% ;
        height:auto ;
    }

    .column img.no-image {
        background:red url(image-pending.jpg) no-repeat center ;
    }
</style>
```

The problem is Blank image always shown as square;
Because of *natural sizes of blank.png is 1x1*.
It seems "height:auto" reset or ignore HTML defined sizes (275x385),
Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akkara/Gg5tg/1/) for examine,
How to fit it like first image **without JS**?

**Edit:** I think This can be solved only with JS manipulations: [My solution](http://jsfiddle.net/akkara/Gg5tg/5/), Thank you for advices below!

Comment: I wish I could start a bounty for this question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can consider doing this in CSS. Have a no-image like this:

http://www.mnit.ac.in/new/PortalProfile/images/faculty/noimage.jpg

Now for all the images, give this CSS:

```
img {background: url("no-image.png") no-repeat center center transparent;}
```

So, this way, the images to be loaded will show No Image and then those with no image, show this. :) [DeviantArt](http://www.deviantart.com/) uses the same technique. Do check this out.

Comment: Sorry I didnt get your approach, could you show it via JSFiddle?

Comment: OKay, gimme a minute... :)

Comment: But its still look square, second image has to be same sizes with first image :(

Comment: @Digerkam Found the issue. Check now: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/Gg5tg/3/

Comment: What if there was a third image which height was 600px?

Comment: @Digerkam Tell correctly. Do you have images of different sizes?

Comment: Yes ofcourse, there are so many images with different sizes. It is responsive approach, static definitions will useless :(

Comment: @Digerkam Still I don't get your exact use case. What do you wanna do? An image has flexible height, and you want them to show a `No Image` image, when the image is not accessible right? The first solution of mine actually works for you. Do check it out. Explain me if I didn't understand the use case clearly! :)

Comment: I found the problem, but I have no answer for it yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789049/browser-do-not-take-care-of-img-element-based-size

Comment: Yeah... This is a peculiar problem of browsers, when handling the images.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
.column img.no-image {
    background:red url(image-pending.jpg) no-repeat center ";
    height:385px;
}
```

Comment: Nope, defining static values are very bad for my condition.

Comment: ok, then why not make the image-pending.jpg the height of 385px?

Comment: Beacuse there is so many images with different sizes, 385px is just for that image, it will useless for others

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not misunderstanding your question, i think you can try using css property background-size .

```
<style>
.column img.no-image {
    background:red url(image-pending.jpg) no-repeat center; 
    background-size:275px 385px;
}
</style>

    <img id="second" class="no-image" src="blank-1x1.png" />
```

if you still have to write the inline style css of width&height inside the  at html, doesn't it supposed to add the 'px' after the number of size you write?

for some more useful documentation, you can surf into  **http://www.w3schools.com**  :)