# Browser Do Not Take Care Of IMG Element Based Size

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I have been experimented this problem recently;

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <img id="first" width=275 height=385 src="flower-275x385.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img id="second" width=100 height=400 src="flower-275x385.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img id="third" width=500 height=150 src="flower-275x385.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img id="fourth" width=75 height=150 src="flower-275x385.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img id="fifth" width=750 height=550 src="flower-275x385.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .row {
        width:100%;
        overflow:hidden ;
    }
    .column {
        width:20% ;
        float:left ;
    }

    .column img {
        width:100% ;
        height:auto ;
    }

</style>
```

On HTML side there is many different sizes for same image,
But browser only take care of **image natural sizes**,
This is why all images rendered same size on result side in JSFiddle,
Hot to force browser to take care of HTML based width/height?

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akkara/e2jQD/2/) of it.

**Edit:** It seems there is no way do it without JS: [My Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/akkara/e2jQD/12/), thanks for advices above there!

Answer (score 0):

[Take the `width:100% ;` out of your CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/e2jQD/3/) if you want the sizes specified in the markup to apply.  Otherwise all the images will be sized to match the width of their containers, and you've set all the containers to be the same width.

Comment: It looks messy, But it would be have same "width"

Comment: @Digerkam I'm not sure what your comment is supposed to mean?

Comment: Sorry for my english, I mean they look messy. They have to be in same width, but different height.

Comment: @Digerkam Then why have you specified different widths in the markup?  The only way to change the aspect ratio of the images is to specify both a width and a height, if you use images that are all the same width and height, forcing them to an equal width will also force them to an equal height.

Comment: Because I experimented this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788608/image-size-via-css?lq=1 I needed to resize images that according to given HTML values

Comment: @Digerkam But that doesn't change the *actual* *size* of the images.

Comment: thats the problem I am trying to tell with my poor english: Browser doesnt take care of HTML values of an element if it was defined in CSS side

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the same width but auto-calculated heights, first remove the style for height that you have applied on the images:

```
.column img {
    width:100% ;
    /*height:auto ;*/
}
```

Then, remove all of the width and height values from your images:

```
<img id="first" src="flower-275x385.jpg" />
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/e2jQD/10/

Comment: @Digerkam - Added jsfiddle links.

Comment: I have seen, but no luck: http://jsfiddle.net/akkara/e2jQD/8/ and http://jsfiddle.net/akkara/e2jQD/9/

Comment: Those images have same height, but on the HTML side you can see many different sizes. So I need to show images according to given HTML width/height values, not according to image's own natural sizes..

Comment: If you use a different image src for each of the images in the the JSFiddle I linked, they will all have the correct height value applied automatically.